# Android Studio - Don't notice phone

Tags: android, android-studio

Welcome , I've a problem with Android Studio , i don't know why but the program can't find my phone , that obviusly happens when i try to test a program directly to my phone , i just can't find the dispositive into the the Android Device Manager.
I have a Samsung S3 , I'd setted the same Android version into the program ( same of my phone Android 4.0.4) , i'd eneble the "USB debugging" into my phone , but the program can't find the dispositive .
I'd tried to change the computer and than the problem didn't verified . 
My pc find the phone correctly it is a problem of the program. Do you have any solution ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enabled Android Debug Bridge for USB (developer section in phone settings). You may also try to reboot your phone.

If the problem still persist it is probably a missing driver that causes the problem. If so, then :

Open **Android Studio** > click on **Android SDK Manager** [image] > **SDK Tools** > install **Google USB Driver**

Hope it will help

Comment: thank you , It could be a driver problem , i will istantly try to install the Google USB Driver.